# Why would an alien species want to hand out FTL technology to lesser races that it deems "worthy"?

Tags: society, science-fiction

I am developing an idea where humans are deemed "worthy" of FTL technology by a humanoid alien race in 2020. The biggest problem I have though is imagining a scenario where the aliens would want to uplift another race.

Giving other species FTL capabilities would only seem to increase the galactic competitiveness for the relatively small number of habitable worlds.

Definition of "worthy" is having had nuclear technology and averting self-destruction for 50+ years.

Comment: Those are pretty lax requirements for being "worthy". Doesn't give me a lot of hope for our galaxy. That being said, you're asking us to basically make up the story for you. This is very opinion based. For example they might need allies in a war. Or trading partners. Or they're simply getting us to test very experimental and dangerous tech. How would one answer be superior to the other?

Comment: I think 50+ years may be a bit too short. We've been developing both nuclear weapons and nuclear reactors for much longer than that, but I still wouldn't trust most governments with FTL technology.

Comment: @AndreiROM Good point though I wouldn't go so far as to say "writing the story."  I will try to better the question when I have the time; probably tomorrow.

Comment: I agree with AndreiROM and I also think this question is too broad.

Answer (score 7):

Some years ago, a friend of mine at work came up with an answer. The common trope of flying saucers and alien encounters doesn't make sense, as anyone intelligent enough to invent the technology would know how to make it look like an indigenous aircraft and otherwise stay hidden.

He proposed that the smart aliens give the flying saucers to some less-intelligent race because they are *funny*. The trope-causing aliens are enabled for the amusement of the really smart ones.

Consider a far advanced civilization where anything is possible and most things are easy. How do you remain stimulated and interested in life, and not stagnate as a culture?  Various art forms and projects that are huge in scope but "pointless" would be what they do with themselves.  Giving advanced tech to some freshly evolved sapient and then following them around with a camera is exactly the kind of thing someone might do.

If it's anything like some "reality" TV, the crew is chosen not for normal job ability and skills, but just the opposite: to be a dysfunctional clash of personalities guaranteed to prove entertaining to the sponsors.  So, a very different fitness function then what you might assume as being "worthy"!

They may have been inspired by Gilligan's Island. Be careful before taking them up on their offer of a free FTL ship to be crewed by carefully chosen humans!

Comment: Alternatively, you can pick a good crew and then throw a bunch of space wedgies in their way,  one at a time.

Answer (score 5):

Their reason is explained on a plaque in the FTL ship's control room...

All intelligent life pursues technical advancement to delay their eventual extinction.

Originally land-locked and limited to a subset of our planet's available climates, we invented clothing, shelter, fire-making and ships.  With them, we spread out across all the viable lands of our world.  We found safety in our dispersion.  Across ages, we survived droughts and famines which killed off whole continents of our people.  Yet our species survived.

As soon as we were able, we created spacecrafts and colonized the worlds of our solar system.  Once that was done, we declared ourselves above the dominion of the planet killing deaths.  No single asteroid or plague could bring us all down.

Centuries past before our technology opened the keys to the stars.  With it, we spread across the galaxies.  Now we can outlive our sun and even a visit from a wandering black hole.  We are everywhere, and no physical force can end us.  The solar system deaths and the galaxy deaths no longer rules us.

There remains only one singular force which still calls us to our graves; the limits of our own genetic potential.  The river of evolution, which carried us from the slime to the stars, will someday return us back to mindlessness.  Our science has proven that this end must come.  We may hold it off for a million, million years, but someday the spark shall fade from our eyes.  Intelligence is an aberration and the universe will tolerate us for just so long.

We give you this spacecraft today, so that you can join us in the stars.  Bring your people up from your world and lift them up out of the dominions of the lesser deaths.  Make your people as immortal as mine, so that together we can fight the one death which still haunts us; the limit of each of our genetic potentials.

Comment: So sort of the opposite of the "singularity"? How can this be *proven*, and why would it be true even with the population dispersed to many different environments?   Aren't they in command of heir own evolution now?

Comment: Rather than descending into mindlessness wouldn't a species potentially reach a post-physical level through evolution or technological advancement? What I mean to say is, are you quoting a theory here, your own personal opinion, or simply setting up a plot?

Comment: Just setting up a plot.  Who knows what we may learn about our genetic future as we advance in all the sciences towards FTL travel.  And who knows what unsolvable problems might be lurking further down the path of our learning. This is borrowed from Niven, whose Puppeteer aliens had scientifically proven that they had no afterlife, and as a result become cowardly, hiring and equipping other races to do the dangerous exploring.

Comment: As conjectures go, this goes back further than Larry Niven. There is something similar in Olaf Stapledon's Last and First Men (1930) where attempts by more advanced descendant human species to create superhumans failed due to their incapacity to comprehend how to do this successfully. Few of us understand what our own limits are, this could apply equally to understanding what our genetic limits are. The average span of existence for a vertebrate species is a million years. We have 900,000 years before our expiry date. Postulating unsolvable biological problems is a concept worth entertaining.